# Wrong EventLogQuery

Tags: c#, .net

The code below gives me an exception with the message `The specified query is invalid`. The exception happens at the assignment of `elReader`.
What is wrong here?

```
string logType = "Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational";
string query = string.Format("*[System/EventID=1116[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{0}']]] and *[System/EventID=1116[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '{1}']]]",
    startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"),
    endTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));

var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(logType, PathType.LogName, query);
var elReader = new EventLogReader(elQuery);
```

This is the contents of `query`:

> *[System/EventID=1116[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '2018-07-26T07:51:57.7239606Z']]] and *[System/EventID=1116[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '2018-08-02T07:51:57.7353333Z']]]

Comment: Can you post the resulting `query` variable contents?

Comment: query = "*[System/EventID=1116[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '2018-07-26T07:51:57.7239606Z']]] and *[System/EventID=1116[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '2018-08-02T07:51:57.7353333Z']]]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error, this Syntax works:

```
string query = string.Format("*[System/EventID=1116] and *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{0}']]] and *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '{1}']]]",
            startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"),
            endTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
```